# Creating a custom Vector class errors

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, dynamic

So I am trying to create a custom class that functions like a vector. It is supposed to have a default constructor that creates an empty vector with a capacity of 2, a parameterized constructor with a capacity of `n`, a destructor, a function to return the size of a vector, the capacity of a vector, a function to delete the data and reset a vector to capacity 2, a `push_back` function to put `n` at the end of a vector, and a function to return the value stored at `n`. I have the majority of the code written out, but I am receiving errors on the driver.cpp file whenever I try to use the `.capacity()` function to show the capacity of the "vector". Errors are

> too few arguments in function call' and `Vector::capacity`: function
>   does not take 0 arguments

every time I try to use `capacity()` in driver.cpp. Please help

```
//Vectors.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "driver.h"
#include "targetver.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Vector
{

double* arr;  // pointer to the first element of this myvec
int cap; // number of elements arr can hold (i.e. size of underlying array)
int n;        // size of this myvec
int sz = 1;

// Increases the capacity of the underlying array to be sz. If sz
// is smaller than the current capacity then nothing is done.

// create an empty vector
void increase_capacity(int sz)
{
    if (sz <= cap) return;

    double* new_arr = new double[sz];   // allocate a new array

    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    { // copy old vector into new one
        new_arr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    cap = sz;                      // set the new capacity

    delete[] arr;                       // delete the old vector
    arr = new_arr;
    }

public:

Vector()
{
    arr = new double[sz];
}

Vector(int n)
{
    arr = new double[n];
}

int size() const 
{
    return n;
}

void push_back(double x) 
{
    if (n >= cap) increase_capacity(2 * cap);
    arr[n] = x;
    ++n;
}

double capacity(int i, double val)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= n) cout << ("range error");
    arr[i] = val;
    return val;
}

double at(int n) const 
{
    if (n < 0 || n >= n) cout << ("range error");
    return arr[n];
}

void clear()
{
    delete[] arr;
    Vector();
}

~Vector()
{       // destructor
    delete[] arr;
}

};


//driver.cpp
const int TEST_VALUE1 = 21;
const int TEST_VALUE2 = 31;
const int TEST_VALUE3 = 41;
const int MAX = 12;

int main( )
{
// Create a default vector 
Vector sam;

// push some data into sam
cout << "\nPushing three values into sam";
sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE1);
sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE2);
sam.push_back(TEST_VALUE3);

cout << "\nThe values in sam are: ";

// test for out of bounds condition here
// and test exception 
for (int i = 0; i < sam.size( ) + 1; i++)
{
    try
    {
            cout << sam.at(i) << " ";
    }
    catch(int badIndex)
    {
        cout << "\nOut of bounds at index " << badIndex << endl;
    }
}
cout << "\n--------------\n";

// clear sam and display its size and capacity
sam.clear( );
cout << "\nsam has been cleared.";
cout << "\nSam's size is now " << sam.size( );
cout << "\nSam's capacity is now " << sam.capacity() << endl;   
cout << "---------------\n";

// Push 12 values into the vector - it should grow
cout << "\nPush 12 values into sam.";
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    sam.push_back(i);

cout << "\nSam's size is now " << sam.size( );
cout << "\nSam's capcacity is now " << sam.capacity( ) << endl;
cout << "---------------\n";

cout << "\nTest to see if contents are correct...";
// display the values in the vector
for (int i = 0; i < sam.size( ); i++)
{

    cout << sam.at(i) << " ";
}
cout << "\n--------------\n";

cout << "\n\nTest Complete...";

cout << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Here are the requirements for my class, of which are relevant:

> 1. A default constructor that creates a vector that is empty. Its size will be zero and its capacity will be two. Remember that size refers to the number of elements currently stored in the vector.
> 2. A parameterized constructor that creates a vector of capacity n. Its size will initially be zero.
> 3. A function size( ) that returns the size of your vector. The size is defined as the number of integer values that have been stored in the vector. The size will change as integer values are added.
> 4. A function capacity( ) that returns the capacity of the vector. The capacity is defined as the number of integer values that can be stored in the vector. The capacity changes when the vector grows.

Comment: You can edit your question.  No reason to put further information in a comment - just put it in your question.

Comment: Your `capacity` function takes an int and a double `double capacity(int i, double val)`, yet you call it with no parameters.. exactly like what your error message says.

Comment: `sam.capacity()`

Comment: Off topic: I would expect a method called capacity to return the capacity, not the value of an element. Strange this is. Violates the Law of Least Surprise it does. Down this path lies the Dark Side.

Comment: A good example is available at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60484/stl-vector-implementation

Comment: -Hariom Singh, i did look at that code and even tried some of it out, Visual Studio kept throwing errors about the use of 'template'
-user4581301...it is supposed to return the current capacity of the 'vector' as an int so it can be printed

Comment: when I try to include the varaibles in the function it throws errors about 'int i': type name not allowed and type int unexpected.

Comment: If you don't understand how `capacity` definition should look like, *you could not have possibly written the rest of this class*.

Comment: -n.m. That's because everything written in driver.cpp was prewritten and I was REQUIRED TO USE AS IS. Everything else I must write and it must work with driver.cpp. I have been working on it for hours and renamed and changed so many things (not always across the entire program) that I could no longer tell you what goes where.

Comment: Here's one possible source for your code http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/125/tjd/vector_example.html You or someone else have made an effort to adapt it to the requirements of your class, but for some inexplicable reason renamed `set` to `capacity`. The only way that woud happen is through absolute lack of understanding of what either function is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

Your defined `capacity` method takes two arguments, the way you've made it. It probably shouldn't, because as you are trying to use it, it should be purely dependent on the object and just return the value you want. You have the choice between providing arguments: `Vector::capacity(i, var)`, or changing your definition to accept 0 arguments.

From what I understand about the actual `Vector` class method `capacity()` in C++, you shouldn't be taking any arguments. However, from what I understand about your definition of `capacity`, you're modifying a component, which you **do** need to supply both a float and an int, which you are not doing when you write `Vector::Capacity()`.

The first part of your code seems strange (*preceding* `public:`), since it is not a constructor but you seem to be initializing a vector. Also, your variable `sz` should be renamed to `cap`, since it is the capacity, not the size, and your variable `n` to `sz` since it is the size.. (I understand why you are confused...)

To keep things easy for myself I changed the `double*` to a `double`. Feel free to change it back. I also wrote `sz` as `size` because two letters make it a lot prettier to look at.

```
class Vector
{

// initialise array myvec in constructors.
int cap; // number of elements arr can hold (i.e. size of underlying array)
int size;        // size of this myvec (same as n)
```

At this point, there is no use to "create an empty vector" outside of a constructor. Therefore I moved the bit here into the two constructors.

```
public:

Vector()
{
    double[2] arr; //creates an array of size two, that is empty.
    cap = 2;
    size = 0;
}

Vector(int n)
{
    double[n] arr; //creates an array of size n, also empty.
    cap = n;
    size = 0;
}

int size() const 
{
    return size;
}


void push_back(double x) 
{
     if (size >= cap) increase_capacity(2 * cap);
     arr[size] = x;
     ++size;
}

double capacity()
{
    return cap;
}
```

The rest of the functions seem ok. Note that I may not have gotten the memory management right, especially with the constructor. If I did, I was bound to get it wrong. I hope you can figure that out.

**EDIT:** After looking at the `pushback` method, I now see why you had the `increase_capacity` method. Here's an edit relative to my code:

```
void increase_capacity(int new_cap)
{
//if (sz <= cap) return; THIS IS NOT NEEDED, since the function is only called when size > cap.
double[new_cap] arr;   // allocate a new array - Note that once again I'm not using pointers, you may want to change this.

for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
{ // copy old vector into new one
    new_arr[i] = arr[i];
}
cap = new_cap;                      // set the new capacity

delete[] arr;                       // delete the old vector
arr = new_arr;
}
```

Comment: At this point I am just lost. I've stared at this thing for hours and I don't know which way is up anymore. I have tried and the code is due in 2 hours. Here are the original requirements of the code:

1. A default constructor that creates a vector that is empty. Its size will be zero and its capacity will be two. Remember that size refers to the number of elements currently stored in the vector.
2. A parameterized constructor that creates a vector of capacity n. Its size will initially be zero.

Comment: @jonthie Definitions 4 and 5 are what you must pay attention to: The capacity of the Vector must be predefined, and it's like an open slot to fill with size, but maybe later. The default constructor, for example, must have capacity 2 but size 0, so `arr` should be an empty array of size 2. _Note that array of size 2 is not a vector of size 2._ `Capacity()` would return `arr.length()`, so in this case, 2. Size is only the same as capacity if the vector is full, if not, it will always be less than capacity. Do you get it?

Comment: I go from language to language quite a bit, so without an interpreter at hand, I may have trouble getting the syntax perfect, but I'll edit my answer to contain some of the code you may want to use.

Comment: What seems to be the problem is how you use `n`, `sz` and `cap` borderline-interchangibly. You don't need **both** `n` and `cap`. (If you think you do, try to explain what the difference between the two is)

Comment: I would rather not have all three either, but it is part of the class requirements I was given to have a non-parameterized constructer with a capacity of 2 and size of 0, and a parameterized constructer with a capacity of n and size of 0. So I can either have all three or have cap = 2 for the first one and cap; for the second.

Comment: -Maxime Franchot, if I am reading your edits correctly for increase_capacity() I need to swap 'size' and 'cap' where they are used correct?

Comment: @jonthie In the sense that you are given `n`, it makes sense. What you misunderstand is that it is **only** used **within** the constructor `Vector(int n)`, and not outside. As for `increase_capacity()`, I'll add the edit to my answer.

Comment: -Maxime Franchot, the at(int n) function and push_back(int n) function also require the use of int n

Comment: @jonthie But in those examples, it's the same: The variable `n` is only used in the context of the function, and is deleted right afterwards. It is a local variable. It is not used **instead** of `size`, rather, it is used as a temporary variable to store the function input, which is then somehow integrated with `cap` or `size`.

Comment: I also added the `increase_capacity` method to my answer. I noticed that you made a very clear misname that can only result in confusion: `increase_capacity(~~)` clearly takes a **capacity** as input, right? You named yours `size`, which is very confusing for yourself as you continue coding the function. Make sure to be very clear on what variable means what.

Comment: I sort of get why you have both `n` and `size`, because `n` is meant to be the current value to be filled, while `size` is the size, but if you think about it, they are still the same thing in that context. When you have a function `size()`, and it returns `n` rather than `size`, that is a clear red flag. Maybe you have to name your variable `n` `size`, and `size`, something else, if it really is different!

Comment: @jonthie Do you know the difference between global and local scope variables? Because the `at(int n)` function and the `push_back(int n)` function clearly use a local variable `n`, which means `n` should not exist outside the scope of those individual functions.

Comment: Yes, it was just slightly confusing as to the wording.

Comment: @jonthie I feel like I have helped as much as I could. The effort I'm putting into explaining this isn't really going anywhere as you can see with the votes on my post, so I'll leave you with what I've written so far. You may want to restart your code from scratch if you are so confused, but keep things very clear for yourself. I honestly think if you only use the variable `n` in a local scope, within the two functions, then you will be fine. I hope I was useful.

Comment: -Maxime Fanchot, you have been more than helpful. thank you for your time.